# How can I reverse each row of numbers in this file in my array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, text-files, reverse

EDITED CODE

the text file with the rows I am trying to reverse contains these numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40  
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50  
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60  
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70  
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80  
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90  
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

so far my array looks like this:

```
 static void Main()
    {            
            int numbers;

            StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(fileDirectory);
            string line  = fileReader.ReadLine();
            fileReader.Close();
            string[] Split = line.Split();
            int.TryParse(line, out numbers);

            int[,] Table = new int [10,10];

                for (int row = 0; row < Table.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < Table.GetUpperBound(0); column++)
                    {

                    }
                }


                for (int row = 0; row < Table.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < Table.GetUpperBound(0); column++)
                    {
                        int tempHolder = Table[row, column];
                        Table[row, column] = Table.GetUpperBound(0);
                        Table[row, Table.GetUpperBound(0) - column] = tempHolder;
                        Console.WriteLine(Table[row, column]);
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }Console.Write(" ");
        }
```

can you help me with adding the int numbers variable to the array and then I will attempt the reversing. Right now if I run this I get about 24 lines of the number 9. Also can someone show me how to do a 2d array without having to specify the size of it? I have looked online but cant find out how. Thanks

Comment: The simple solution would count how many lines there are.  Creating an array of the correct size based on that information, and loop backwards through the empty array.  I suggest you try this method and ask any questions based on that code.  You don't even attempt to fill the array.

Comment: I ninja edited the comment to exclude the comments about 10 x 10 since mnel's edit made it clear.  Of course the problem you will face is creating the correct size array.  There is a solution to that problem of course.  You just can use an integer array to do it.

Comment: Not clear to me if you are trying to reverse the numbers for each row or the whole file. If it's each row then you don't need to count the lines as @Ramhound suggested. after `line = fileReader.ReadLine()` just split the line by space, put it in the array and read the array backwards

Comment: I guess I should have posted my attempts at filling it but I have tried many different approaches and all failed which is why I asked for help here but I'll put my last attempt in the question

Comment: I am trying to reverse the numbers by each row

Comment: @user1849989 - Please take the time to preview your post before you hit submit.  What results do you get exactly?  Provide a sample size of the output you get and post the result you want.  If you want to reverse the order of each row thats really easy, already explain one method, just adapt for each row.  You would just read the row, count forward, then count backwards.  After you get to your previous starting point you would count forward 10.  You need to come up with an algorithm to do this, we wouldn't actually be helping you learn, if we actually provide you one for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is homework, so I'll give some advice but stop short of actually providing code.

Firstly, you'll have to Split each line to get a list of strings representing each number.
After that you need to Convert the string representation of each number to an integer.
Then it shouldn't be too hard to loop through and add each int to the array.
You will need to keep track of the current horizontal index while processing a line, and vertical index across all lines.

After that you should be much closer.  Have a go at doing the reversal and come back if you have problems again.

Edit:

For creating the array, you can specify the size from int variables.  If you had `String[] lines` (one for each line) and `String[] line` (a line from `lines` split by the space character), you could declare the array like so:

```
int[,] table = new int[line.Length, lines.Length];
```

You're getting pretty close with this code.
For String.Split, you need to tell it which character separates the elements you want:

```
String[] split = line.Split(' ');
```

This needs to be done once for each line in the file, so it should be moved inside the outer loop.  Similarly, `int.TryParse` needs to be done once for each number, so it should be inside the inner loop.

```
int number;
if (int.TryParse(split[column], out number))
{
    table[column, row] = number;
}
```

You should also watch your `GetUpperBound` calls.  `GetUpperBound(d)` returns `GetLength(d) - 1` so you need to loop while the index is les than or equal to `GetUpperBound`.  You could also replace the `GetUpperBound` calls with `GetLength(0)` (Columns) and `GetLength(1)` (rows).
The number passed to `GetUpperBound` and `GetLength` is the direction you want to get the size in.  You're passing 0 to all of these, which won't work unless the array is square.

In the reversing loops, there's an error on the second line of the inner loop.  You're setting `Table[row, column]` to the size of the array, instead of the element to be swapped.  You also only need to loop in to the middle of each row, otherwise you'll just swap the elements back to their original positions on the last half.

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying a lot of different solutions for over 11 hours today and just failed. I am new to arrays and I have been finding it difficult to understand fully but I'll give this a try in the morning since it is now 00:30

Comment: @user1849989 No worries.  It can do more harm than good trying to work when you're frustrated/tired.  I'll expand on this answer a bit later based on the new code posted.

Comment: @user1849989 - Programming is hard.  Some problems takes days, weeks, and even months.  This problem isn't that complicated.  I suggest you break the problem down, figure it out on paper, then write your code.  How would you reverse something like this yourself?  Write down each step to solve the problem, this is your first step, in solving the problem.

Comment: I have made a few changes to my code, I will attempt the try and catch once I get to work but can you guys help me with adding the int numbers to the array as in all the values in there will be the 10 by 10 in the array. One more thing, can you show me an example of how to have a 2d array without having to specify the size of it.

Comment: @user1849989 I've added more information.  Hopefully that should get you the rest of the way, but I'll check back in a bit if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @TheEvilPenguin I have finally gotten it to read the file and display it. I am now about to attempt the reversing so I will let you know about that.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some more hints, tips and provide some of the code.

1.. You need to get the values from the text file into an array

```
string arrayLine = "";

try
{
    StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Numbers.txt");
    string line = fileReader.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);

        if (arrayLine != "")
        {
             arrayLine += " " + line; // Add the rest of the number lines together
        }
        else
        {
             arrayLine = line;  // Add the first line
        }

        line = fileReader.ReadLine();    
    }
    fileReader.Close();
} 
catch (IOException IOEx)
{
    throw new Exception("no file found");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Other Exception found");
}

// Add the numbers into an array
int[] myNumberArray = SplitStringToNumbersArray(arrayLine);
```

the method for Split String To Numbers Array is below

```
static private int[] SplitStringToNumbersArray(string _Numbers)
{
    _Numbers = _Numbers.Replace("  ", " "); 
    string[] pieces = _Numbers.Split(' ');
    int[] ret = new int[pieces.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = int.Parse(pieces[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

2.. You want to reverse the array. Here is an example and information

[Reverse an Array in C#](http://www.deepakkapoor.net/reverse-array-elements-using-c/)

3.. The array has been reversed so now you want to go through the array (starting from the 99th position and decrement) and add 10 numbers to each line. Ill give you the skelton code for it, you can fill the rest in

```
string result = ""; // Used as the temporary string

for (int i = (reversedArray.Length-1); i > -1; i--)
{
    if ((i % 10 == 0))
    {
        // this is the 10th number you are adding to the string
        // This string is complete, What should you do now? 
    }
    else
    {
        // Keep adding to the string  
    }
}

// You have completed it so add the next line so you can see the result
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but you could make your last algorithm work without hardcoding the size of your array.  What happens if you add another row? Now you'll have to recompile and shouldn't need to.

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo Great point. I have updated the answer to reflect your suggestion

Comment: Also, just a nit-pick, but you're assuming that a newline is supposed to follow every 10 characters--another thing you'd have to change.  But, much better with the change.  =)

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo they are all valid points :) I guess I just wanted to put up an answer quickly so it could help out the OP. Cheers for taking the time to comment

Comment: No worries. Like I said, just a nit-pick. Gave a +1 for your fix to help you break even. =)